# Complex php if statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate all different combinations for something that have x>=y, x<=y

ex: $abc <= 123 && $abc >= 123 && $abb >= 123 && $abb <= 123 && $acc >= 123

however, I don't want things such as "$abc <= 123 && $abc >= 123" to be saved (I'd want the combination: $abc <= 123 && $abb >= 123 && $acc >= 123 to be saved, no conflicting arguments), so I'm trying to use an if statement to filter them out, sometimes there are multiple conflicting arguments such as "$abc <= 123 && $abc >= 123 && $abb >= 123 && $abb <= 123" but I'm having trouble

```
    $string = '$abc <= 123 && $abc >= 123 && $abb >= 123 && $abb <= 123 && $acc >= 123';
     if(substr_count($string, "abc <=") == 0 && substr_count($string, "abc >=") == 1 || substr_count($string, "abc <=") == 1 && substr_count($string, "abc >=") == 0)  {
        echo("hello");
    }
```

In this statement it won't return hello, which is right, but once you remove one conflicting argument from $string it will return hello, but I don't want this because still another conflicting argument exists. Is it possible to do something like this or I must do something like:

```
substr_count($string, "abc <=") == 0 && substr_count($string, "abc >=") == 1 && substr_count($string, "abb <=") == 1 && substr_count($string, "abb >=") == 0
```

Please advise

Sorry if this is a poorly asked question, it's hard to explain

Comment: if `$abc < = 123 && $abc >=123` is true then surely `$abc=123`?

Comment: I asked this poorly, that was just a random example, it has to be a >=/<=, $abc will never be absolutely equal to the number

Comment: Then use `if($abc!=123)`

Comment: The 123 really has nothing to do with it, it's generating millions of possible combinations, like: $abc <= $var_1 && $abc >= $var_1 && $abb >= $var_2 && $abb <= $var_2 && $acc >= $var_3, I want to catch the conflicting arguments i.e.;  $abc <= $var_1 && $abc >= $var_1 cancel each other out, if you use that it'll never work, so I'd only want it to save $abc <= $var_1 OR $abc >= $var_1, thats why I have the substr_count($string, "abc <=") == 0 && substr_count($string, "abc >=") == 1 bits

Comment: Might be missing something, but agree with @Scott here.  If $abc < = 123 && $abc >=123 then if($abc=123).  If $abc <= $var_1 OR $abc >= $var_1 then if($abc!=$var_1).  You seem to be over complicating things here.

Comment: Let me get this straight... you're building a string that contains a PHP conditional statement, and then trying to check that parts of the string don't contradict each other? Why on earth are you doing that? Can I assume that you're planning to use `eval()` on it later? Ouch. The very fact that you're building an executable statement as a string indicates that you're doing something pretty fundamentally bad. I think you need to take a step back: ask yourself what you're actually trying to acheive, and see if there's a better way you can do it.

Comment: I can't really say why I need to do it, but basically there's a bunch of statements in an array and it's generating all combinations of the objects of the array, some contradict each other.

Comment: Also it's okay if it's not very good/clean coding right now, it's not for use in production, just the results of what I'm generating will be used in production if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [bitmasks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) are for.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post with some additional information on bitmasks for the person asking the question.

Comment: I think he might be right, researching now, will accept answer once I learn more

Comment: Thank you Jan, helped a lot.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment: This is actually German. "Sven Kahn" sounds to me German as well, that is why.

Comment: @Jan Please excuse my ignorance!  Well done however that is very considerate of you.  The only thing I will say is that English is the main language of stack overflow and it is a resource site.  Other users can view this question for help in the future, so you should include an English link as well.  I know it is very easy to change `de` to `en` in the URL, but some people are not so bright.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment: Right you are, I have updated the link.